# Loading CSV file into MYSQL database not importing rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have the following function:

```
    function bulk_insert_file($filename) {

        $file_location = 'assets/temp/'.$filename;

        $sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '."'$file_location'".' INTO TABLE p4p.users_csv_import
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
            LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'
            IGNORE 1 LINES';
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

And the following CSV file:

```
,2,unique_id,first_name,last_name,email,company,nonprofit,username,password,dimension_data,raw_csv_data,
,2,unique_id,first_name,last_name,email,company,nonprofit,username,password,dimension_data,raw_csv_data,
,2,unique_id,first_name,last_name,email,company,nonprofit,username,password,dimension_data,raw_csv_data,
```

However, when I run the code no data is imported. If I remove the IGNORE 1 LINES part I will at least get the first row imported.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_csv_import` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `unique_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `first_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `company` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nonprofit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(34) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dimension_data` text,
  `raw_csv_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the specs on the table..

Comment: Strange. `IGNORE 1 LINES` should cause it to skip the header... unless there is a line break above it?  The import may be failing because id and unique_id are empty strings.

Comment: Actually, it is ignoring the first line now, the headers, but after making the above adjustments it is still not importing.

Comment: If ID is an int it can only be numeric. Since it is AUTO_INCREMENT you should probably leave it out of the file import completely.

Comment: I was able to get it to import the first line. However, it will not import any additional lines unless I put a field terminator ',' at the end of every line.

Comment: Did you try removing the ID?  Or use valid numeric IDs

Comment: The above csv file works but I would like to be able to remove the trailing ',' at the end of every line? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the csv file is in unix line terminators format.
You should therefore try importing with `LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'`.